# shared context with GLUT on Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, opengl, textures, glut

In my current setup, I have two displays that are being driven by two GPUs. Using GLUT, I create two windows (one per display) and render each one from the main thread by calling glutSetWindow() in the draw call, for each window.

The draw calls renders a Texture2D as a sphere (using gluSphere()) but the Texture2D is swapped for another image every few seconds. I have set up an array of 2 Texture2D so I can load the next image while the current Texture2D is shown. This works well as long as everything runs in the main thread.

The problem is that the call to glTexImage2D(), to load the next image, hangs my draw call, so I need to call glTexImage2D() on a different thread. Calling glTexImage2D() on a different thread crashes, as it seems the OpenGL context is not shared. GLUT does not seem to provide a way to share the context, but I should be able to get the context on Linux via glXGetCurrentContext().

My question is if I get the context via this call, how can I make it a shared context? And would this even work with GLUT? Another option has been to switch to different library to replace GLUT, like GLFW but in that case I will loose some handy function such as gluSphere(). Any recommendation if the context cannot be shared with GLUT please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GLX context sharing is established at context creation; unlike WGL you can't establish that sharing as an afterthought. Since GLUT doesn't have a context sharing feature (FreeGLUT may have one, but I'm not sure about that) this is not going to be straightforward.

> I have two displays that are being driven by two GPUs.

Unless those GPUs are SLi-ed or CrossFire-ed you can't establish context sharing between them.

> The problem is that the call to glTexImage2D(), to load the next image, hangs my draw call, so I need to call glTexImage2D() on a different thread.

If the images are of the same size, use glTexSubImage2D to replace it. Also image data can be loaded asynchronously using pixel buffer objects, using a secondary thread that doesn't even need a OpenGL context!

Outlining the steps:

**In the OpenGL context thread:**

*initiating transfer*

- `glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboID)`
- `void *p = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY)`;
- signal transfer thread
- continue with normal drawing operations

**In the transfer thread**

*on signal to start transfer*

- copy data to the mapped buffer
- signal OpenGL context thread

**In the OpenGL context thread:**

*on signal to complete transfer*

- `glUnmapBuffer`
- `glTex[Sub]Image`
- `sync = glFenceSync`
- keep on drawing with the **old** texture

on further iterations of the drawing loop

- poll `sync` with `glClientWaitSync` using a timeout of 0
- if the wait sync returns signalled switch to the new texture and delete the old one
- else keep on drawing with the old texture

Comment: Thanks datenwolf, this is pretty great! I switched to glTexSubImage2D() and it seems to already be a small imrpovement. I am trying to write all the code for the async data loading. Can you please recommend how to signal the OpenGL context thread when the transfer thread is done? Do you know if calling glutTimerFunc() with 0 msecs timeout a safe solution? Or should a synchronized boolean should check in the draw call that the transfer thread is done? Thank you!

Comment: @Jary316: The usual approach would be [*condition variables*](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs241/sp2012/lectures/25-condition.pdf)  which are polled from the GLUT idle function. Using a CV has the benefit, that the polling thread goes to sleep while waiting for the variable (and in case of a 0 timeout another thread will get schedules, which may free up the CV). Of course with strong latency requirements simple spin-locking on a **atomically** accessed boolean works as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am getting it close to working! It's fading slightly, but not fully, but I mean just need to tweak some parameters! I had to a call to glBufferData() right after glBindBuffer() but before glMapBuffer() (please tell me if that's wrong).

Comment: @Jary316: The idea is to create a large-ish PBO (glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData)  at initialization and (re-)use that as staging area for all further transfers (just glMapBuffer glUnmapBuffer) –. In principle you can do a lot of [funny tricks using buffer orphaning](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming). In general the idea is that you want to minimize the amount of calls to glBufferData and glTexImage (always try to do things using the "…Sub…" variants).

Comment: Quick question: why is the glClientWaitSync / glFenceSync needed? Both calls happen in the context thread, so I was thinking I may just be able to swap the texture right there. What do you think?

Comment: that makes complete sense, thanks, I should initialize the PBO ahead of time. Thanks!

Comment: @Jary316: The purpose of the fence is, that you don't use the texture for drawing until the OpenGL driver is done loading the texture; remember that everything which doesn't require an explicit synchronization will happen asynchronously. Calling glTex[Sub]Image you're asserted, that once the function returns the data has been transferred (and you can discard the memory the data is read from), so calls like this impose synchronization. And a PBO is used to allow for asynchronous glTex[Sub]Image (and the synchronization moved to copying the data into the mapped buffer).

Comment: @Jary316: But when loading image data from a PBO into the texture takes some time as well, despite not blocking your program's execution. But the moment you use the texture as sampling source OpenGL has to wait for the transfer to complete (synchronization) which may cause the program to stutter. By using a fence to delay using the new texture until the asynchronous texture load has completed this kind of stuttering is avoided.

Comment: ah thanks a lot!! It all makes sense. It works really well! Right now it sometimes crashes during the memcpy() for a reason I can't quite figure out, but it does not happen often so there may be some race there. When this bug does not show up, it works really really well! Thanks, you've solved my problem, thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks @datenwolf, I got it fully working and stable now! Performance seems great, but I will thoroughly test tomorrow. I've learned a little of OpenGL thanks to you!